# jquery and hover intent - best way to disable hoverintent plugin

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

I have to disable the use of hoverintent plugin, however I have no control over existing source code on the page. So at the moment I'm just throwing in a brick like so:

```
$("ul#accordion li").hoverIntent( null )
```

Is there a better way to do this than passing a null instead of 'real' config elements?

thanks

Comment: Then what is the purpose of using hover intent? Functions that control what happens when you hover go within there.

Comment: ... it was a part of a multi level accordion menu where sub categories were hidden. Unfortunately for me the page was 'set in stone' so to speak and all I could do is add a chunk of JS at the bottom of the whole kludge :-( to restructure the whole menu. At the end I had to disable hoverintent as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about overriding the plugin? Something like:

```
$.fn.hoverIntent = function(){ return $(this); };
```

Comment: ... tried no joy yet, but it gave me an idea to look at other possibilities.